# Encrypt DB password in NodeJS application before building and pushing docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

Infrastructure setup:

- Docker Desktop environment running on MacOS,
- A Minikube cluster is also running on this MacOS.
- Jenkins pod running on the Minikube cluster

I have this NodeJS application that talks to a MySQL database(A docker container) to retrieve a text string from a database called hello_world.  I need to encrypt the database password before building the application within a NodeJS image.  This image will then be pushed to the DockerHub repository.

It will then be downloaded and installed as a pod in the Minikube cluster via a Jenkins Pipeline in the dev namespace.  There is a MySQL database pod already setup in the ‘dev’ namespace in which subsequent stages in the pipeline will test the retrieval of the text string from the database.

```
➜  nodejs-app git:(main) ✗ cat app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'dev-mysqldb',
  user: 'mysqluser',
  password: ‘xxxxxxxx’,
  database: 'hello_world'
});

//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Mysql Connected...');
});

//show all products
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
//    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
    res.send(results);
  });
});

//Server listening
app.listen(80,() =>{
  console.log('Server started on port 80...');
});
```

I have 2 questions here.

1. How do I encrypt the database password in the above NodeJS application?
2. How do I make Kubernete pod decrypt the database password which was originally setup in the docker environment?

Thanks.

Comment: just set the database password with an environment variable and store it as a kubernetes secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach here is to use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme).

**Usage**:
Create a `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
S3_BUCKET="YOURS3BUCKET"
SECRET_KEY="YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE"
```

As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv:

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it working
```

.. or using ES6?

```
import 'dotenv/config' // see https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import
import express from 'express'
```

make sure to take a look at https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme for more information.

Comment: Hi futaba, I adopted your solution since it is not exposing the database password in the application.  Though it is still did not encrypt the database password, for this demo it should be sufficient.  Thanks.